# ReaciveCrudRepository with Awaitility

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, awaitility

writing tests and not sure how can one rewrite this code:

```
SomeEntity entity = Awaitility.await()
            .atMost(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .until({ -> repository.findById(id) }, { entry -> entry.isPresent() })
            .get()
```

to reactive one:

```
SomeEntity entity = Awaitility.await()
            .atMost(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .until({ -> repository.findById(id) }, { entry -> entry.???() })
            .block()
```

Note:

first findById() signature is:
Optional findById(Long id)

second findById() signature is: Mono findById(ID id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do something like this:

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(1, SECONDS).until({ ->
                Transaction transaction = repository.findAll().blockFirst()
                transaction.currency == USD
                transaction.amount == 20})
```